# Universal Control: Mouse pointer keeps jumping back to computer 1 when working on computer 2

Tags: macos, monterey, universal-control

I've started using Universal Control to be able to switch between devices with just one mouse (MX Master 3) and without toggling on the mouse. This works fine as soon as I move the mouse pointer to the edge, it appears on the other computer. But if I work something with Safari (e.g. write this text) and then move the mouse again, the pointer is always on the other computer. So it's all unusable. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: I guess it's still in the beta phase cause whenever I also use that it sucks.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the mouse (applies to the Logitech keyboards as well) going to sleep or power save mode.

If using this on a solo Mac without Universal control, the mouse will become unresponsive for a second or two until it wakes back up and starts communicating with the Mac again.  If using with Universal control, this reconnection seems to “reset” the mouse back to the main monitor.

I have the MX Master 3S, an MX Anywhere 3, a K380 keyboard and a KeyChron K8 and they all go into sleep mode and when waking up, they all are set for the main display.  I have found that the Logitech’s Flow seems to work better.

Answer (score 0):

In my case both computers had a mouse connected. As soon as the original mouse moved a bit, my remote mouse jumped back to its screen.

This even happened by tapping on my desk, because the mouse laser was very sensitive.

Solution was to lay the sensitive mouse on its back.

Comment: I tried this, even switching the mouse off, unplugging it may help 10 seconds, but the focus gets back to the main screen (MacBook Pro). It's just unusable. Any advice is welcome.